# Unrecognized field "attachment" when POSTing a Chatter FeedItem with a file

Tags: rest-api, chatter, json, attachment, feeditem

I'm attempting to create a new Chatter `FeedItem` using the Salesforce REST API. I'm constructing a multi-part request with the following parameters:

```
{
  "feedElementType": "FeedItem",
  "subjectId": "005o0000000Eg9AAAS",
  "type": "text",
  "text": "Here is the content of my FeedItem post"
}
```

The first part of the request contains the image data, and the second part contains JSON data about the feed item. Here's the JSON being passed in under the `name` of `json`:

```
{
  "body": {
    "attachment": {
      "attachmentType": "NewFile",
      "title": "file.png"
    },
    "messageSegments": [
      {
        "type": "Text",
        "text": "this is a test text"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

When I get a response back, I'm getting an `HTTP 400` with the following error from Salesforce:

```
{
   errorCode = "JSON_PARSER_ERROR";
   message = "Unrecognized field \"attachment\" at [line:-1, column:-1]";
}
```

I know that this is definitely recognizing the image file (stored under the `name` of `feedElementFileUpload` in the multipart request) because I was getting a different error when I encoded the image incorrectly. Does anyone know why I'd be getting this error?

Here's the Objective-C code sending the request using AFNetworking 2.0:

```
NSArray *message = @[@{@"type": @"Text", @"text": @"this is a test text"}];
NSDictionary *file = @{@"attachmentType": @"NewFile", @"title": @"file.png"};
NSDictionary *body = @{@"body": @{@"messageSegments": message, @"attachment": file}};

NSDictionary *params = @{@"feedElementType": @"FeedItem",
                         @"subjectId": kUserID,
                         @"text": @"example text",
                         @"type": @"text"};

[[AT_WebHelper sharedSalesforceNetworkMgr] POST:kSFEndpointPostToChatter parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

    //Add the file if there is one
    if (self.photoTaken.image != nil) {
        NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.photoTaken.image);
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:data name:@"feedElementFileUpload" fileName:@"file.png" mimeType:@"image/png"];
    }

    //Add the attachment metadata
    NSDictionary *headers = @{@"Content-Type": @"application/json; charset=UTF-8", @"Content-Disposition": @"form-data; name=\"json\""};
    [formData appendPartWithHeaders:headers body:STR_DATA([Universal jsonStringForObject:body])];

} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
    NSLog(@"RESPONSE: %@", operation.responseObject);
}];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In v32.0 and higher of the API, you need to use capabilities instead of attachments. See the example for [posting a feed item with existing content](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/quickreference_post_feed_element_content.htm) to get an idea of what you need to do. For posting a feed item with a new file, there are examples in the section about [uploading binary files](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/intro_input.htm#cc_upload_binary_files).

The API reference to look at is the [Feed Item Input](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_requests_feed_item_input.htm#connect_requests_feed_item_input) page.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! Adding a `capabilities` item in the `json` with the data from your [uploading binary files reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/intro_input.htm#cc_upload_binary_files), as well as the `subjectId` fixed the problem!